# Can we have a notification when the answer to any of my question got edited?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, answers, notifications

If a user asked a question and got an answer which was not helpful.

After sometime the answerer edits the answer with some good content. How the OP will get to know that?

Is it necessary to add comment *check my edited answer*?

We can say that the OP should refresh the page to find the helpful answer.

Consider if the OP finds the answer as helpful and accepted that. After sometime if the answerer/anyother user edit the answer to change the content which may not solve the issue.

How will it be notified to OP?

currently we are notifying the OP when there is any comment to the queation or any new answers or any comments with the name of OP with @ to any answer.

This will lead the future visitors to confuse and reduce the quality of post.

Can we have a notification to the original poster when the answer to any of his/her question got edited?

Answer (score 6):

I completely agree with @Azik, there can actually add a small checkbox while editing an already answered post, which says `Notify the OP`. So, if that check-box is checked, the OP is notified. In this way unnecessary commenting will be avoided...

Comment: Making this a user option seems like a potential abuse mechanism. Besides bumping the post, there is a user facing control to annoy the OP. I actually think the notifications SHOULD happen, but why not just make them automatic? Seems like a more natural flow.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be a good thing to do in the future, but also unnecessary to do because the posts won't get any better with editing, and the editor won't edit the whole answer anyway 
if he thinks that he has a better answer. He will post it and is not going to edit another answer with a better solution.

Comment: If answer's author feels he made mistake or was not clear enough, he *will* edit. Edits by others should not really trigger notification as they aren't supposed to change meaning, but edit by one who posted answer is different, and happens quite often.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @AhmedAli, because it will be annoying and the post really won't get any better that goes to accepted, but I also agree with @CRUSADER; the checkbox to notify the OP is a good idea... Better than randomly notify them, only if the edit was good enough for it then the editor checks the box to notify him.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a good thing to have as the answer can get edited for fixing some grammatical mistakes, errors in the code or to add additional information which can be useful for OP.

Even given links in the answer can also sometimes be changed.

It will be a better idea to have something like a `FAVOURITE` option for answers which the OP wants to get connected or updated whenever the answer is edited. Even other users who wish to be updated with an answer should have this option.

This type of option can be helpful when the questions are opinion based and which are expected to change in the future.