# Are there de facto rules for suggesting edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I recently edited and got rejected twice for [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2830486). I've read the editing rules and this seems like a good edit to me. The original code provides no context, nor does it even compile, and the author admits himself that it's untested and theoretical.

From [SO Editing Page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) it reads to me like I'm doing the right thing, but now I'm wondering if there are some unwritten rules about editing that I haven't picked up on yet.

Comment: Formatting is not the same as making broken code working code. The latter is a new answer

Comment: The editing page states _To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages_. The answer is nearly correct, save a few _minor_ mistakes.

Comment: Sure, but something answer-worthy is not a "minor mistake or update".

Comment: @Dennis I can see how it would be answer worthy if no answer already existed. A new answer would be almost identical to an existing answer.

Comment: If what you are trying to add in is in an existing answer, then *definitely* do not put it in an edit.

Comment: @Dennis I'm not sure what you mean. The original answer was correct, save a few untested mistakes. A new answer would present an entirely different approach/idea, no?

Comment: Not necessarily. If two people are trying roughly the same approach, but one person does it correctly, while the other makes subtle but important mistakes, I'd call them two separate answers.

Comment: @Dennis Depends, the answerer repeated it's untested code makes it essentially pseudocode. Assuming that there aren't even _mistakes_ present.

Comment: It's not up to someone else to fix someone's untested code. If it's broken, then point it out and get him to fix it. Downvote the post if you think it'll get the point across. But don't fix it *for* him.

Comment: @Dennis Okay, but can you explain what _To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages_ means? I am confused on this point.

Comment: Minor mistakes like typos or formatting. Updates as in further research that builds to the post

Comment: @random You closed this question as a duplicate of a question about editing code in **questions**. This meta question is about editing code in an **answer**, which your proposed duplicate does not discuss.

Comment: Jim, you were doing the right thing. Editing typed-in-browser code to working code that implements the same solution is a good thing. This is spelled out in the [rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) of Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, you were the victim of reviewers who feel that the rules don't apply to them. Thank you for the good work, and please continue improving Stack Overflow. Hopefully you'll shortly have enough reputation to do so unhindered.

Comment: Indeed, Jim, I think your behavior is benchmark. I think some users believe that people who make programming mistakes in their answers should be "punished" by not having their answers improved and that those finding the mistakes should get credit (via separate answers) for finding and fixing them. I don't believe this is in the spirit of SE, while you're behavior most certainly is. Also, I agree this is not a dup, but I don't have the MSO rep to fix that. Keep up the good work and thank you for setting an example for all of us.

Comment: See also [my answer to a related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188499/editing-add-a-require-author-approval-checkbox/195338#195338). The fact that this question was closed as a duplicate of an unrelated question is an example of the confusion that is being made between editing code in questions (which is almost always a bad thing) and editing code in answers (which isn't intrinsically good or bad).